# How use closures in swift like Java interfaces

Tags: java, swift, interface, closures

I have a hardcoded snipet of code in java like below. How can I rewrite this code on Swift 3 using protocols or another swift stuff.

```
interface Startable {
 int started(String name);
}

class A{
    private String name;
    private Startable startable;

    public A(String name, Startable startable) {
        name = name;
        startable = startable;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (startable != null) {
            startable.started(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your attempt at implementing it in Swift, along with the problem you're having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Java Example `Startable` is a "Functional Interface" which comes next to that in Swift is called "Function Type" and I think that is what you mean with `Closure`, see the "Function Type" section in [Swift Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158).

From the Swift Documentation:

> **Function Types**
>
> Every function has a specific function type, made up of the parameter
>   types and the return type of the function.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> func addTwoInts(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
>     return a + b
> }
> func multiplyTwoInts(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
>     return a * b
> }
> ```
>
> This example defines two simple mathematical functions called
>   `addTwoInts` and `multiplyTwoInts`. These functions each take two Int
>   values, and return an Int value, which is the result of performing an
>   appropriate mathematical operation.
>
> The type of both of these functions is `(Int, Int) -> Int`.
>
> ...
>
> **Using Function Types**
>
> You use function types just like any other types in Swift. For
>   example, you can define a constant or variable to be of a function
>   type and assign an appropriate function to that variable:
>
> ```
> var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts
> ```
>
> This can be read as:
>
> “Define a variable called `mathFunction`, which has a type of "a
>   function" that takes two `Int` values, and returns an `Int` value.’
>   Set this new variable to refer to the function called `addTwoInts`.”
>
> ...

If you want to do exactly the same as in your java example then you could write in in Swift as

```
class A {

    var name : String
    var startable : ((String) -> Int)?

    init(_ name : String, _ startable : ((String) -> Int)?) {
        self.name = name
        self.startable = startable
    }

    func doSometing() {
        if let fn = startable {
           fn(name)
        }
    }   
}
```